# jquery ui automated drag and drop effect

Tags: jquery

I wanted to know if there is any jquery plugin which has a effect of drop (i.e automated drag and drop). If I click on some button or icon the div containing it should be dropped into another div. Using CSS3 is not an option for me.

Comment: DOM manipulation + [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: @FlorianF. I went for that and I am glad I did. Worked out well for me thanks.

Comment: Just one problem though the animation doesn't work very well in chrome and safari (webkit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are list of few libraries which are used to drag and drop:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

http://jquery-plugins.net/category/drag-and-drop

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/drag-drop-jquery-plugins/

http://gridster.net/

Hope these will help you.